# Whether SQL query will work if there are no indexes on the relations?

Tags: sql, database-indexes

GATE1999_2.25

Which of the following is/are correct?

```
A) An SQL query automatically eliminates duplicates
B) An SQL query will not work if there are no indexes on the relations
C) SQL permits attribute names to be repeated in the same relation
D) None of the above
```

This is GATE 1999 Competitive exam question. It is easy to eliminate option A & C. Please answer whether option B is correct or not, and why?

I've gone through SQL chapter of multiple databases and also searched online but I have not found any reference to impact of indexes on an SQL query, which can answer this question.

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL : "The standard does not specify database behavior in several important areas (e.g. indexes, file hostorage...), leaving implementations to decide how to behave.."

Comment: An SQL "relation" can have duplicate "attribute" names. However an SQL base variable can't contain one of them. Eg `SELECT * FROM t a JOIN t b`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In any reasonable database you could create a table with no indexes or keys (which would implicitly generate an index), insert data into it, and query it.

Consider the following (syntax may slightly vary, depending on the RDBMS you're using, although I've tried to be as generic as possible):

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (mycol INT);

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1);

SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

No indexes whatsoever, and the query works perfectly. Answer B is just incorrect.

Comment: Oh. Actually That was the confusion I had, that implicit indexes are always created. As index are always created implicitly this situation of not creating index does not really appear. Though we need not create explicit index B is incorrect ! This GATE questions are little confusing !  Thanks :)

Comment: @abcd If you don't declare an index but a DBMS internally does what it would have done if you had declared one, or if you do declare an index but a DBMS internally does what it would have done if you had not declared one, then that is a detail about its implementation, not about SQL. An SQL index is a thing that you declare explicitly or implicitly that exists conceptually, like a base table or constraint. A PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint implicitly declares an index as if you had declared one explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

SQL query will not automatically eliminate the duplicates , explicitily we have to use distinct keyword for removing duplicates from result set.

If there is no indexes it will create index automatically.

No two column can have the same name.

Hence None of the above is true